# NHibernate: Session.Save and Transaction.Commit

Tags: nhibernate

Is there a difference between `Session.Save` and `Transaction.Commit` ?

When I should use which?

It seems that sometimes `Session.Save` must use in conjunction with `Transaction.Commit`, sometimes no. Can anyone tell why this is so?

Comment: Transmission.Commit or Transaction.Commit?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They're differenrt-- `Session.Save` saves an object and `Transaction.Commit` commits a bunch of work (multiple Gets, Loads, Saves, Updates, etc).

You'll want to use both. Here's a quick explanation with a link for more reading. The NHibernate documentation says the following:

> In an `ISession`, every database operation occurs inside a transaction
>   that isolates the database operations (even read-only operations).

If you don't explicitly define your transaction, one will be created implicitly every time you read from or write to the database. Not very efficient. So even if you're just reading, you'll want to put everything inside a transaction and commit the transaction when you're done. Ayende Rahien explains further in [this blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/28/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged.aspx).

When you look at some code samples out there, it may seem like people aren't using transactions but they may just be beginning/committing the transaction outside of the code you're looking at. In my ASP.Net MVC app, for example, I use an action filter (TransactionAttribute) to handle the transaction outside of my Controller Actions.

Comment: Nice explanation: +1 for the TransactionAttribute suggestion