# org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Tags: mysql, windows, hibernate, jsf-2, jboss

I have a hibernate and JSF2 application going to the deployment server and suddenly throwing an org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in exception. I will provide the stack trace and code immediately but here are four important issues first:

1. This happens only on the deployment server (Jboss & MySql running on Windows Sever 2008.) It does not happen on my development machine (Tomcat and MySql running on Windoes 7 Pro) and also not on the staging environment (Jboss and MySql running on Linux.)
2. Researching this, it seems that people get this error when trying to insert an object. But I get the error when I'm doing a simple query. (various different queries, actually, as the error pops up on several pages randomly.)
3. The error hits only every now and then. If I do a Jboss restart it goes away, but a time later returns. Also, it's not consistent, on some clicks it's there, on others it's not. Even when it hits, when I do a simple refresh of the page it returns fine.
4. I'm using c3p0 (config below)

Any idea what's going on?

The code details:

This happens on an address object. Here's the full hbm:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.idex.auctions.model">
<class name="Address" table="address" lazy="true">
  <id name="addressID" column="AddressID">
        <generator class="native"/>            
  </id>

  <property name="street" column="street"/> 
  <property name="city" column="city"/> 
  <property name="zip" column="zip"/> 
  <property name="state" column="state"/> 
  <property name="region" column="region"/> 
  <property name="country" column="country"/> 

  <many-to-one name="user" 
       class="com.idex.auctions.model.User" 
       column="userid" 
       unique="true" 
       cascade="save-update"/>
 </class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The Java class is straight forward:

```
public class Address implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7485582614444496906L;

private long addressID;
private String street;
private String city;
private String zip;
private String state;
private String region;
private String country;
private User user;

public Address() {

}
public long getAddressID() {
    return addressID;
}
public void setAddressID(long addressID) {
    this.addressID = addressID;
}
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getZip() {
    return zip;
}
public void setZip(String zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getRegion() {
    return region;
}
public void setRegion(String region) {
    this.region = region;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

}
```

The c3p0 configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1000</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>  
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

The versions used are

```
hibernate3.jar

c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar

myfaces-api-2.1.4.jar

myfaces-impl-2.1.4.jar

mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar
```

The full stacktrace

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.idex.auctions.model.Address entry 
    (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(
                                          DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:78)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(
                                          DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:187)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(
                                          DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:143)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(
                                          AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(
                                          AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(
                                          DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:58)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:997)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1142)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
com.idex.auctions.manager.DatabaseManager.getAllObjects(DatabaseManager.java:464)
com.idex.auctions.ui.NavBean.gotoHome(NavBean.java:40)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor350.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:735)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:467)
javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:246)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(
                                          ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:96)
javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:246)
javax.faces.component.UIOutcomeTarget.getOutcome(UIOutcomeTarget.java:50)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils.getOutcomeTargetHref(
                                          HtmlRendererUtils.java:1542)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlLinkRendererBase.renderOutcomeLinkStart(
                                          HtmlLinkRendererBase.java:908)
org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlLinkRendererBase.encodeBegin(
                                          HtmlLinkRendererBase.java:143)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:502)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:744)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:758)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:758)
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(
                                    FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1900)
org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(
                                    PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(
                                    ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:93)
com.idex.auctions.ui.CustomViewHandler.renderView(CustomViewHandler.java:98)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:115)
org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:126)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118)
```

Comment: If all else fails, you could take a look at the `org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId()` method and trace back where the id that is found `null` coming from, then find out how to set it/ensure it is not `null`.  If the problem is indeed due to the `Address` class, you can put in a break point for where the id is set (maybe a `null` id is passed).  The call is triggered when a flush occurs (which would explain why it is "random": when an auto-flush is required), so you might also want to check on (`Address`?) objects that have not been flushed yet.

Comment: Thanks for this, Attila. Can you please expand on how to get the org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId() method to help me, and how to check on Address objects that hasn't been flushed yet?

Comment: Actually how can the address id even be null, when it's a primitive long?

Comment: I could not find the source for 3.0, but the 3.2 source is available from [hibernate.org](http://www.hibernate.org).  Specifically: [DefaultFlushEntityEventListener](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/3.2/src/org/hibernate/event/def/DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java)  - The exception is thrown, when the `id` parameter of `checkId()` is `null`.  You will need to see where that `id` is comming from (start from the stack trace you provided to see how `checkId()` is called).  The easiest way is to download the whole source and do rearches there.[cont]

Comment: [cont]Note that there might be slight differences in the downloaded code and the library you are using as they have different versions (maybe get a copy of the 3.2 version of the Hibernate library to ensure you are looking at the code that is actually being executed)

Comment: The `id` parameter if `checkId()` is `Serializable id`, so it _can_ be `null`

Comment: can you share some code esp method at DatabaseManager.java:464.
Are you trying to handle exceptions instead of rollback?

Answer (score 59):

The exception:

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Tells us that the session exception has happened **before** the point where this `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure` is thrown.

To be exact, the `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure` is thrown when the `session.flush()` is happening, not the point where the error ocurred.

The above is a fact, thus a possible conclusion from it is: something could be **suppressing** the original exception.

So look for **other** possible points of error: A `save()` or `saveOrUpdate()` is possibly **trying to persist an entity with a `null` field** where, in the table, the column is `NOT NULL`?

---

**TIP:**
To help in the debugging, try adding a `session.flush()` after every interaction with the `Session` object (e.g. `session.save(obj)`, `session.merge(obj)`, etc.), this will hopefully cause the `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure` to happen earlier, closer to where the real problem is taking place. (Of course, after the debugging, remove those `session.flush()`.)

In my case, the **real** exception was taking place inside a `try/catch {}` block where the `catch` suppressed the exception (didn't rethrow or warn me about it).

Comment: How do you fix this?  I am trying to save many entities, in a loop.  Some of which may fail.  How can I get the successful records to persist?

Comment: @DavidWilliams You should have each save in its own transaction, then.

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm doing it in separate transactions but the problem is still there. What should I do to be able to save next items in DB using the same ISession object?

Comment: Perhaps this is a good opportunity to take notice of how absolutely dangerous empty catch blocks are, they can take weeks of time to troubleshoot!  Always have something in there that brings it to the developers attention, at least a .printStackTrace.  If you are absolutely sure you want it to be empty (Checked exceptions CAN lead to such a situation), justify this in comments.

Answer (score 16):

I would bet for a concurrency issue but it may occur at different levels:

- a hibernate session may be shared between different users if the [classical "open session in view" pattern](http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2010/03/open-session-in-view-pattern-spring-jpa/) is not properly implemented
- an entity is shared between two user sessions because of improper [hibernate cache settings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache)
- a JDBC connection is shared between two different hibernate session (less likely)

Apart from these potential sources of troubles, I would remove c3p0 (maybe just rumors...) as your stack already provides `DataSource` with connection pooling integrated with the transaction manager.

Comment: Thanks, Yves. Can you expand on the DataSource with connection pooling, so I will understand why do you suggest removing c3p0?

Comment: Also, I'm not using the open session in vew pattern. All my hibernate code looks like this:  public static List<Auction> findAllAuctions() {
  String sql = "FROM com.auctions.model.Auction order by startDate desc";
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();  
  session.beginTransaction();
  List<Auction> auctions = (List<Auction>)session.createQuery(sql).list();
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  return auctions;
 }

Comment: I have to investigate if such usage may lead to session sharing between threads...

Comment: I propose to remove c3p0 because Tomcat and JBoss already has pooling feature delivered by JavaEE DataSource. Tomcat uses dbcp by default. My idea is just to remove a component that duplicates a feature already available in your app server stack.

Comment: Thanks for the c3p0 explanation. I will remove it.

Comment: Are you sure you do not keep any references as static fields in any of your classes ? Have you run Sonar on your source code ?

Comment: Yes http://www.sonarsource.org/ Such a tool is able to point incorrect coding patterns in a large code base, so like the use of DateFormat instance (which is not thread safe) as a static field... The same way it may raise a violation if you use a static field in a servlet to store anything like an hibernate session

Comment: Thanks, Yves. These are all good ideas and although none of them is a clear solution for my issue they definitely put me in the right direction. (Just explaining why I'm happily clicking the bounty button for this answer.)

Comment: @Herzog - if you solved the problem, could you post your solution as an answer (you can accept it too)?

Comment: Thanks Herzog. I have guessed it is not possible to answer accurately to your problem without looking at your full source code. The way the code uses static methods and the lack of open-session-in-view are definitely clues for concurrency troubles... But refactoring effort may be too much. First, check any static fields in your classes, I hope Sonar may help.

Comment: Hi Atila, I'm not sure I solved it but for now it's gone, if this makes sense. My answer is below and I'd appreciate a feedback.

Comment: In such context, only load testing may bring confidence about  concurrency issues. But it may come back after any maintenance or under really rare conditions.

Comment: Hi @Herzog Have you removed c3p0 connection to solve this issue?

Answer (score 13):

The @asdcjunior has answered correctly. Something has happened before the exception is thrown.

In that kind of situations (it happens often on integration tests when you dealing with single transaction for one test - for example @Transaction annotation) I'm invoking the method:

```
session.clear()
```

It helps because all the 'dirty' objects are removed from current session so when the next flush is executed the problem does not appear.

Example flow:

- insert the assignment entity (many-to-many relation with constraint that could exist only single assignment) -> everything ok
- insert the same assignment entity one more time -> everything ok, controller in this case return some kind of bad request exception, under the hood Spring throws the IntegrityViolationException -> in test everything looks ok
- get the repository and execute findAll().size() to check the count of existed assigned to be sure that we have only single assignment -> the mentioned exception is thrown ;/ what happend? on the session exist still dirty object, normally the session would be destroyed (controller return error) but here we have the next assertions to check regarding database, so the solution here is additional session.clear() before next db related method executions

Example correct flow:

- insert the assignment entity
- insert the same assignment entity
- **session.clear()**
- get the repository and execute findAll().size()

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: This is the most dangerous way to mitigate the pb, if you have others unflushed pending changes in the session than your entity which failed to be inserted everything will be lost, this may lead to completely unexpected behavior in your unit of work

Comment: Where can we get the session in service layer?

Comment: @Gab please could you expand on this ? session.clear() is used in the test, not in the production code, so why would it lead to unexpected behaviour in the unit of work ?

Answer (score 5):

I was facing this issue
I just add try catch block and in catch block I wrote seesion.clear();
now I can proceed with the rest of records to insert in database.

Comment: This was the most useful answer for me. So basically had a Unique constraint on my username field using Spring and Hibernate. Once i followed this advise i could catch the exception without the server throwing a 500 error.

Comment: This is the most dangerous way to mitigate the pb, if you have others unflushed pending changes in the session than your entity which failed to be  inserted everything will be lost, this may lead to completely unexpected behavior in your unit of work

Comment: Where can we get the session in service layer?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably hitting some Hibernate bug. (I'd recommend upgrading to at least Hibernate 3.3.2.GA.)

Meanwhile, Hibernate does better when your ID is nullable so that Hibernate can always tell the difference between a new object that has not yet been persisted to the database and one that's already in the database. Changing the type of `addressID` from `long` to `Long` will probably work around the problem.

The stack trace you provided shows that you are seeing the problem on a query because your query is forcing buffered writes to be flushed to the database before the query is executed and that write is failing, probably with the same insert problem other people are seeing.

Answer (score 3):

Problem flow :

1. You create a new transient entity instance (here an Address instance)
2. You persist it to the database (using save, merge or persist in hibernate Session  / JPA EntityManager)
3. As the entity identifier is generated by the database hibernate has to trigger the database insertion (it flushes the session) to retrieve the generated id
4. The insert operation trigger an exception (or any pending unflushed change in the session)
5. You catch the exception (without propagating it) and resume the execution flow (at this point your session still contains the unpersisted instance without the id, the problem is that hibernate seems to consider the instance as managed but the instance is corrupted as a managed object must have an id)
6. you reach the end of your unit of work and the session is automatically flushed before the current transaction is committed, the flush fails with an assertion failure as the session contains a corrupted instance

You have many possible ways to mitigate this error :

- Simplest one and as hibernate stands "don't flush the Session after an exception occurs" ie. immediately give up and roll back the current transaction after a persistence exception.
- Manually evict (JPA : detach) the corrupted instance from the session after catching the error (at point 5, but if the error was triggered by another pending change instead of the entity insert itself, this will be useless)
- Don't let the database handle the id generation (use UUID or distributed id generation system, in this case the final flush will throw the real error preventing the persistence of the new instance instead of an hibernate assertion failure)

Answer (score 2):

OK, I continued researching based among other things on other answers in this thread. But in the end, since we were up against a production deadline, I had to choose the emergency rout. So instead of figuring out hibernate I did these two things:

1. Removed a jQuery library I was using to grab focus on one of the forms. I did this because I read somewhere that this type of bug may happen due to a form posting a null value -- causing the null id down the line. I suspected the jQuery library may not sit well with PrimeFaces, and cause some form to malfunction. Just a hunch.
2. I killed the hibernate implemented relationship I had between user and address. (just one required, not one to many) and wrote the code myself when needed. Luckily it only affected one page significantly, so it wasn't much work.

The bottom line: we went live and the application has been running for several days without any errors. So this solution may not be pretty -- and I'm not proud of myself -- but I have a running app and a happy client.

Answer (score 2):

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

This just happened to us and I thought I'd add some details for posterity.  Turns out that we were trying to create an entity with a duplicate field that violated a condition:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '' for key
'Index_schools_name'
```

This exception however was being masked because hibernate was trying to *commit* the session even though the create failed.   When the created failed then the id was not set hence the assert error. In the stack trace we could see that hibernate was committing:

```
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit
(HibernateTransactionManager.java:480)
```

It should have been rolling back the session, not committing it.   This turned out to be a problem with our rollback configuration.  We are using the old XML configs and the exception path was incorrect:

```
<prop key="create*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-org.x.y.LocalException</prop>
```

The `LocalException` path was incorrect and hibernate didn't throw an error (or it was buried in the startup log spew).  This would probably also be the case if you are using the annotations and don't specify the right exception(s):

```
// NOTE: that the rollbackFor exception should match the throws (or be a subclass)
@Transactional(rollbackFor = LocalException.class)
public void create(Entity entity) throws AnotherException {
```

Once we fixed our hibernate wiring then we properly saw the "duplicate entry" exception and the session was properly being rolledback and closed.

One additional wrinkle to this was that when hibernate was throwing the `AssertionFailure`, it was holding a transaction lock in MySQL that then had to be killed by hand.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39397836/179850

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me in the following situation:

1. New entity is persisted.
2. Entity is configured with `javax.persistence.EntityListeners`. `javax.persistence.PostPersist` runs.
3. `PostPersist` needs some data from the database to send a message via `STOMP`. A `org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository` query is executed.
4. Exception.

I fixed it by using the following in the `EntityListeners`:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;
import java.time.Instant;
...

ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.class);
scheduler.schedule(() -> repository.query(), Instant.now());
```

Where `ApplicationContextHolder` is defined as:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the length parameter of an entity's field. When I tried to save an object with too long String value in one of its fields, I got the error. The solution was to set the proper value of parameter "length" in hibernate configuration.

```
<property name="status" type="string" length="150" not-null="false" access="field"/>
```

It can also be done with annotation @Length like that:

```
@Length(max=150)
private String status;
```

The hibernate exception's message was very misleading in my case, as was stacktrace. The fastest way to locate where the problem occures is to follow your code with debugger and evaluate *session.flush();* after every *save()* and *saveOrUpdate()* method.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with the Query that is being executed. This just triggers the flush. At this point Hibernate is trying to assign an identifier to the entity and seems to have failed for some reason.

Could you try changing the generator class:

```
<generator class="identity"/>
```

see if that makes a difference. Also have you made sure that the database you have deployed has the correct auto-incrementing column set up on the table?

It sounds like your issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838520/hibernate-problems-with-auto-increment-id-mysql-5).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the generator class:

```
<generator class="identity" />
```

to

```
<generator class="assigned" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exception too, in hibernate config file:

```
<property name="operateType" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="operate_type" not-null="true" />
 </property>
```

when pass null value at object, occur exception

```
 "org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.idex.auctions.model.Address entry",
```

I think the reason because Hibernaye will check 'not-null' property, so, remove 'not-null' property or set 'not-null' for 'false', will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens when length of string is greater than that allowed by DB.

`DataIntegrityViolationException` translates to this exception which is a weird behavior by hibernate.

So if you have `Column` annotation on the String field of the entity with length specified and the actual value is greater than that length, above exception is thrown.

Ref: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/186341?_sscc=t

Answer (score 0):

org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Your getting this error while using the save method, if your maintaining the version history of the user activity and try to set the  following values 
        `setCreatedBy(1);
         setModifiedBy(1);
         setCreationDate();
         setChangeDate();`
}
You will get the above error to solve this you need to create the following columns on table.

`Created_By
  Modified_By
  Creation_Date
  Change_Date`
if you are getting same error while Update method  to solve this problem Just you need to change the Update() method to merge() method that it 
i hope helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case it was because before this exception I executing create query with exception. Exception is caught and don't rollback the transaction in catch block. Then I use this broken transaction in other operation and after a few time I got the same exception. At first I set flush mode to manual

```
public final Session getCurrentSession()  
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
    return session;
}
```

Then I got another exception, that explained to me what happened in fact. Then I done transaction rollback in catch block of my create method. And it helped to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hitting the same error when I make session.getCurrentSession.refresh(entity) it looks more like a bug to me instead of an issue with my code. I'm getting this error in a unit test when I'm trying to refresh an entity in the beginning of a test and that entity is created in the test setup (annotated with junit's @Before). What is strange is that I'm creating 3 entities from the same class with random data at the same time and by the same way in the setup and I can refresh the first two created but the refresh fails for the last one. So for example If I create 3 entities User in the test setup I can refresh user1 and user2 and it fails for user3. I was able to resolve this by adding session.flush() at the end of the code that is creating the entity in the setup. I don't get any errors and I should but I cannot explain why the extra flush is needed. Also I can confirm that the entities are actually in the test DB even without flush because I can query them in the test but still failing the refresh(entity) method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I traced out the error and found that I had not marked my table's **primary key** i.e. 'ID' as 'Auto_Increment' **AI**. Just tick the AI checkbox and it would work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if im late or not, but my issue here was that i was opening an transaction and commiting -> flushing -> closing after the request. However between those did i have a nhibernate save() operator which does this automatically, in that case it complained.

Threw exception:

```
session.BeginTransaction();
model.save(entity);
session.Transaction.commit();
```

Solved for me

```
model.save(entity) //this one should open transaction, save and commit/flush by itself
```

However alot of people says that you should use both, ex [NHibernate: Session.Save and Transaction.Commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332849/nhibernate-session-save-and-transaction-commit).

But for some reason does it work for me now without transactions..

Answer (score -1):

Roll back your transaction in the catch block

Comment: "It seems that people get this error when trying to insert an object. But I get the error when I'm doing a simple query" - based on this statement, it's obvious that the source of the issue needs to be identified (bug, configuration, misbehaving component/framework, etc) and resolved. While the suggestion of using a Rollback would help keep data consistent, it won't resolve the issue in question.

Comment: well just don't catch so :) but yes you're right transaction should be given up